# Twig escaping HTML and rendering as raw

Tags: html, symfony, twig

I hope someone can assist me on this issue.

I am pulling details from a database to display on a twig template (using Symfony2) but the way in which it is saved in the db makes it difficult to interpret the HTML.

Basically, the HTML tags are already translated as entities in the table, e.g.:

```
&lt;p&gt;Bach Flower Crab Apple Remedy:&amp;nbsp;the &quot;cleansing&quot; Remedy can be used both internally and externally&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;
```

And so on. I have researched the rendering options in twig and tried the following (based on me rendering a loop of product descriptions):

```
{% set strategy = 'html' %}
{% autoescape 'html' %}
{{ product.description|escape('html')|raw }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

and also just:

```
{{ product.description|raw }}
```

The first method just echoes the existing content (as entities) and the second method just renders the HTML tags to the page as follows:

```
<p>Bach Flower Crab Apple Remedy: the "cleansing" Remedy can be used both internally and externally.</p><p><strong>...
```

So, as you can see, I cannot find a way to actually interpret the HTML tags in order to display the description as it should be.

Is there a way to do this? I can't do it in the PHP as all it's doing is sending an object to the template which is looped through:

```
public function showAction(Request $request, $store_id=0)
{
    $max = 1000;
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Product');
    $products = $repository->getProductsByStoreId($store_id,$max);
    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $products,
        $request->query->get('page', 1),
        20
    );

    $return['products'] = $pagination;
    $return['categories'] = $this->getCategories();

    return $this->render('AppBundle:tables:productstable.html.twig', $return);
}
```

Comment: So you've got escaped HTML in the database, and you want to output it as raw HTML to be interpreted as HTML? Why is it escaped in your database in the first place? *That's* your core issue which you should rectify.

Comment: If in anyway possible, don't encode the data when storing it into the db. A good read would be [@deceze's "The Great Escapism"](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).  Deceze! Couldn't you wait a few seconds ;)

Comment: @Yoshi I seem to be attracted to these kinds of problems... :D

Comment: Unfortunately I am taking data from an Open Cart database, I have no control over how the data is saved. So, I guess that it's not really something Twig can handle...

Answer (score 2):

Your core issue is that you do not have HTML in your database to begin with. *At best* Twig could be outputting some *HTML entities*, which will render visibly as "<p>...", and at "worst" Twig will escape the text to render it accurately as it actually is, which is "&lt;p&gt;...". Expecting Twig to output actual HTML which will render a *paragraph* is unrealistic, since that's not what your original data contains at all.

You'll have to HTML-decode that text in PHP first, and then output it in Twig with `..|raw`. `raw` means that Twig will output it as is without further escaping it. Since it's nonsense to get the data from the database to then [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) it, you need to fix your *data input* here! ***Don't*** HTML encode data which is going *into* the database, it serves no purpose.

Comment: As I have said in my comment above, I do not have control over how the data is saved as it is controlled by Open Cart and I am simply coding an Admin area which is off the back of that data.

Comment: Well then, the answer is that you need to HTML-decode the data in PHP. You *could* add Twig filters and such to do this in Twig, but that seems misplaced and overkill.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to write custom escaper plugin to decode html entities and use it like this:

```
{{ product.description|myawesomehtmlentitiesdecoder|raw }}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html#custom-escapers for reference.

But generally, it's better to store HTML in database and then apply needed security filters on output.

Comment: if you're coming to this question in 2023, twig docs have moved - see eg  https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/filters/escape.html#custom-escapers